# Visual Studio can't locate SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have created a new database using the SQL Server Object Explorer inside Visual Studio:

[image]

However, when I try to connect to it using my DbContext class by specifying the database name only, it doesn't let me and throws an exception "Error Locating Server/Instance Specified". Now I understand that it doesn't know which server to connect to - but it used to work in the past. Is there something I might be missing? Note that the server is local. Do I have to manually specify the server in the connection string? Why can't I just use the database name?

```
public sealed class DestinyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    public DestinyContext() : base("Destiny") { }
}
```

Comment: you CAN use the database name, but that's not what EF has as a convention. the standard DbContext(string) constructor expects the name of the connection string in your config file or, if that fails, the connection string. of course you can build your connection string from the database name, ConnectionStringBuilders are pretty much there for this purpose. it's just not what the EF developers wanted to have as the standard procedure, as the targeted database could be literally anywhere, not necessarily on localdb, and the db name would not give enough information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could have multiple instances on your SQL Server. Need to check it out, compare the following marked image with your MSSQL Management.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can see that on my management studio. Server name is `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` while it sets on `Windows Authentication` with the same username marked in your image.